# Somar casas decimais JavaScript

Tags: javascript, valor-monetário

Tenho 3 variáveis JavaScript:

```
valorUm = 2.8 //dois ponto oito
valorDois = 2.415 //dois mil quatrocentos e 15
valorLivre = 25 //vinte e cinco
```

O que preciso é:

```
valorUm + valorDois - valorLivre
```

esse calculo me retorna -19.785 e deveria me retornar 2392.8

Estou recuperando os valores de inputs:

```
valorUm = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ab').value.replace(",","."));
valorDois = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bc').value.replace(",","."));
valorLivre = parseFloat(document.getElementById('livre').value);
```

Comment: A conta está certa de acordo com o que você mostrou. O segundo número é 2 ponto 415 e não tem nada mil aí. Se quer mil então o número é `2415`. A conversão parece estar ok. O que pode estar errado é estar vindo em um formato que não é o que você espera. Como estão sendo digitados os valores?

Comment: Os valores vem de calculos automaticos da api do google maps, estou recuperando os valores que vem '2.415 km', removendo o texto e calculando. Mas, esses valores são variaveis, podem ser 10.000 km ou 2 km, ou seja, há algo que possa fazer, para que independente do valor retornado me venha um calculo exato?

Comment: Como está o formato em `bc`? O jeito exato que o número fica?

Comment: no input "2.415 km"

Comment: Consegui, removi os pontos de bc, antes de dar o replace. Funcionou blz

Comment: Foi o que eu respondi.

Comment: Isso mesmo @bigown fiz o que explicou, vlw mesmo cara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a descrição do comentário a mudança necessária deve ser esta:

```
valorDois = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bc').value.replace(".", ""));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/RemovePoint.js).

Ainda está estranho o outro `replace` mas se você acha que está certo, não vou questionar. Não gosta de converter um número que contenha texto mas deve dar certo neste caso. Eu acho estranho uma API mandar dados desta forma para serem consumidos.

Answer (score 0):

No meu projeto DEU CERTO dessa maneira:

```
    var quantidade = $('#quantidade').val().replace(",",".");

   var valorUnitario = $('#valor_unitario').val().replace(",",".");

   var valorTotal = parseFloat(valorUnitario) * parseFloat(quantidade);

   $('#valor_total').val(parseFloat(valorTotal));
```